# Understanding Laravel Migrations - Do you need to create a mrigration file

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have a database with tables already made and I also already have a connection to the database that is working.

My Question is: Do I need to still create a Migration file in order to save, update or delete data from the database?

Comment: No you do not need to create migration files if you already have a database. The migration files are there to help you re-create the same database structure on different environment.

Comment: Thank You for your response and answer. I am new to Laravel and I am trying to edit various data that exist on the database. Do You have any links or information on updating data , deleting data etc..? 

I found a few videos on it but you never know if others have a better knowledge base for things.

Answer (score 0):

If this data is going to be permanent and you do not have a "admin panel", then you can create a migration.
**Example:** if you want to add a particular "user", you can create a migration for that.

I think it depends on what "type of data" and how recurrent you will need to do that.